# Strange unexpected tokens inside the string

Tags: r

I have two simmingly identical strings in two data frames. For example, both

```
df_cont$winner[20]
df_assist$winner[609]
```

return "ivarovskaya"

But the comparison

```
identical(df_cont$winner[20], df_assist$winner[609])
```

returns FALSE.

So, dplyr joins don't work on them and when I count characters in those strings, I get different numbers.

Then I found out that copying those strings from View() panel into Rscript results in this:

[image: unexpected tokens in string]

Output of problem variables looks like this:

```
> df_cont$winner[20]
[1] "iva­rov­ska­ya"
> df_assist$winner[609]
[1] "ivarovskaya"
> nchar(df_cont$winner[20])
[1] 14
> nchar(df_assist$winner[609])
[1] 11
```

dput() function also results in identical strings:

```
> dput(df_cont$winner[20])
"iva­rov­ska­ya"
> dput(df_cont$winner[20])
"iva­rov­ska­ya"
```

How can I get rid of those strange red dots?

Comment: can you copy & paste the output of `dput(df_cont$winner[20])` and same for `df_assist`?

Comment: Added output of two pieces from problem variables and counted characters in them. May it help, if I provide part of my datasets?

Comment: **Can you please** copy & paste the output of `dput(df_cont$winner[20])` and same for `df_assist`, as Michael suggested? We are asking you to do this because it will help.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! Although output of dput() looks the same in console, these strings are really identical now. So, my problem is solved.